# Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails. This application works fine on my local machine, and deploys without any problem. But when I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I get this error:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.1269
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["postgresql gem is not loaded" error deploying a Ruby on Rails application on Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759711/postgresql-gem-is-not-loaded-error-deploying-a-ruby-on-rails-application-on-he)

Comment: @SimoneCarletti The post that you are referring was posted much after mine.

Comment: I know. I came across the same question a few hours ago, I pick the one with the best answer and I flagged the others as duplicate so that new users will not be confused. Accidentally, the one I selected as the main one is younger than yours. The comment was automatically posted by SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this line to your `Gemfile` inside the `:production` group (add one if you don't have it).

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

It's very clear from the error its self that gem `pg` needs to be added to your `Gemfile`. You might be using `sqlite3` in your development but Heroku uses `postgresql` for their database.

Your `Gemfile` should look like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'


gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.0'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  
end
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: If you are on Mac OS X, dont forget to have postgresql installed using `brew install postgresql`

Comment: I have `gem 'pg'` in my gemfile under `group :production`. But I still get the error. I am on OSX and I have done `brew install postgresql`. Any clue?

Comment: @UniSoundWaterloo I have the same issue, any clue?

Comment: I did a fresh build and it works. I wasn't sure why.

Comment: @UniSoundWaterloo try `bundle install --with postgres`

Comment: I had the same situation, I already have `pg` gem in my `Gemfile` and adding a specific version just fixed the error: `gem 'pg', "0.21.0"`.

Answer (score 54):

simply adding gem 'pg' to the gemfile didn't work for me.

This worked for me

gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'

Got this answer from

[Heroku and Rails: Gem Load Error with Postgres, however it is Specified in GEMFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261996/heroku-and-rails-gem-load-error-with-postgres-however-it-is-specified-in-gemfi)

Thanks to Piers C

And yeah, gem 'rails_12factor' helps when it's time view Heroku's logs for error messages.

Comment: After spending too much time this comes as rescue for me.

Comment: This happened to me again after updating to 1.0, just released. Still works!

Answer (score 2):

I am using ruby 2.3.8. If you are unable to solve this issue, the problem can be with the version of pg you are trying to work with. Replacing `gem 'pg'` with `gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'` worked out well for me. Also, This is my database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: 5
development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  reconnect: true
test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_DB'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USER'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PORT'] %>
  min_messages: notice
production:
  <<: *default
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['DB'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

And this is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
# Adding pg gem for postgres
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: It worked for me with Ruby 2.3.8 and Rails 4.0.13.

Answer (score 1):

I got the error when upgrading gitlab. I executed the wrong command, saying `sudo -u git -H bundle install --without postgres development test --deployment` instead of `sudo -u git -H bundle install --without mysql development test --deployment`

Simply executing

`sudo -u git -H bundle install --with postgres` did it for me, in your case probably

`bundle install --with postgres` and afterwards the db migration,
`heroku run rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

You can also fix it by upgrading rails to a >= 5.1.5 version.

Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31673