# "postgresql gem is not loaded" error deploying a Ruby on Rails application on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use **postgresql** with **Ruby on Rails** on **Heroku** but got an error

```
Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please add your `Gemfile` and `database.yml` files.

Comment: ***Heroku*** supports only `postgresql` FYI.

Comment: add pg gem and run bundle install ...then setup database using heroku run rake db:migrate

Comment: What were the reasons for Heroku choosing PostgreSQL over MySQL?
Please refer this link http://www.quora.com/What-were-the-reasons-for-Heroku-choosing-PostgreSQL-over-MySQL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `Gemfile`

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Then run `bundle install` and try to deploy on Heroku.

If you want to use PostgreSQL on all environments and not only in `production` (recommended) add the gem outside the `:production` group and remove other database adapters such as `sqlite`.

As a side note, you may also want to add the [`rails_12factor`](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem as suggested by Heroku.

Answer (score 25):

This worked for me

`gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'`

Thanks to Piers C

Got this answer from

[Heroku and Rails: Gem Load Error with Postgres, however it is Specified in GEMFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261996/heroku-and-rails-gem-load-error-with-postgres-however-it-is-specified-in-gemfi)

Comment: simply adding  gem 'pg' to the gemfile didn't work for me. Seems to be a version issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, also commit gemfile.lock,  after doing bundle update

Answer (score 7):

Add pg in gemfile

```
 gem 'pg', '~> 0.20'
```

then bundle update & commit Gemfile & Gemfile.lock to heroku.
simple include like gem 'pg' will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following version into my gemfile, and it is solved.

`gem "pg", "~> 0.18"`